# Does Concourse CI log who manually triggers and aborts builds?

Tags: concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-fly

Concourse CI provides an easy way to trigger and abort pipeline job builds via the web interface or the fly CLI.

I haven't found a way to determine who performed these actions after the fact.  Is this information logged somewhere that can be accessed by users?

The information displayed on the web page and accessible by the `fly watch` command doesn't appear to contain these details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was the work-around to viewing this, you can enable auditing and check the logs ([Check_Here](https://concourse-ci.org/concourse-web.html#audit-logs)).

But there was one open issue related to display who triggered job in the UI ([Check Issue here](https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/4120))